# Send image from non-ui class to activity

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-activity, android-broadcast

I need to send Bitmap from non-ui class to activity so i can use it or directly update ui from non-ui class. How can i do that. Is localbroadcastreceiver is only option here or is there any easy method to achive my goal.
**Edit**:
I am receiving that image from a socket connection and want to update ui with that image.

Comment: Interfaces - the same way you'd pass data between threads in plain Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to send the actual `Bitmap`.Sending a path to the image could work well for you if you 're working with `Intents` and inter process communication but if it is in the same process then passing the reference is done the same way you do with any pojo.

If it is a network image. You might cache it on disk or in memory depending on size of the image.

PS; You might want to make your question a bit less ambiguous

Comment: Actually i am receiving that image from a socket connection.And i want to update ui using that image.

Comment: I managed that by saving image to memory then sending activity a message that it can now read image.

Comment: @user6657161 awesome. It's quite simple. Just tell the activity "Hey,  I 've just got the file from a socket, here is the path to it, you can read it now." I find `BroadCastReceiver`s useful for passing messages around in Android

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make that method `static` and you can then use it in your non-activity class as:

```
public class MyBitmap{
 public static Bitmap getMyBitmap(){

         Bitmap bitmap = Get your bitmap from the socket connection
    return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Then in your `activity class`:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(MyBitmap.getMyBitmap());
```

Comment: Good but can't use it becuase i need to update not set ( as image is not already there)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily achieve with  localbroadcastreceiver. and its good practise rather than apply eventbus or so.. 
may be you are using XMPP something like.
so in localbroadcastreceiver when you get image just get full imagepath from there and pass it to the activity and there load it from path in activity.

Comment: No i am not ;P it was a captcha image.